# Password AutoFill: WKWebView doesn't present "Save Password" alert

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, autofill

I have to authenticate to my app with a web login page using `WKWebView` and to simplify the user experience the Password Autofill feature is added with all required steps:

1. Set up my app’s associated domains. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains)
2. Set the correct AutoFill types to user/password text fields. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element)

AutoFill works correctly and suggests username/password variants from iCloud Keychain in the QuickType bar. But it doesn’t show “Save password” alert as Safari does with the same login page.

How to enable or implement the saving password alert for `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the saving password alert manually by adding/removing correct configured `UITextField` in your view hierarchy:

```swift
func showSavePassword(view: UIView, username: String, password: String) {
  let usernameInput = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
  usernameInput.textContentType = .username
  usernameInput.text = username
  view.addSubview(usernameInput)
  
  let passwordInput = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
  passwordInput.textContentType = .password
  passwordInput.text = password
  view.addSubview(passwordInput)
  
  passwordInput.becomeFirstResponder()
  usernameInput.removeFromSuperview()
  passwordInput.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

To make it work automatically you can implement checking for username/password parameters in `httpBody` for each new request with `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```swift
extension URLRequest {
  // Parse parameters
  var httpBodyParams: [String : String?]? {
    guard let httpBody,
          let text = String(data: httpBody, encoding: .utf8),
          let components = URLComponents(string: "?" + text), // Add '?' to make a valid url
          let queryItems = components.queryItems
    else {
      return nil
    }
    
    return queryItems
      .map { [$0.name : $0.value] }
      .reduce([:], { $0.merging($1) { _, new in new } })
  }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
  
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction) async -> WKNavigationActionPolicy {
    if let params = navigationAction.request.httpBodyParams,
       let username = params["username"] as? String,
       let password = params["password"] as? String
    {
      showSavePassword(view: view, username: username, password: password)
    }
    return .allow
  }
}
```

Comment: In our case the webview won’t return username and password. So how to archive this.